# Comparación de datos que entran por comunicación serial

Tags: python, serialport, pyserial

tengo un problema y es que no puedo comparar una entrada serial que ya fue pasada a string con otro string porque por mas que digan lo mismo me los detecta como distintos, aqui el codigo:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

serialInst = serial.Serial()

portList = []

for onePort in ports:
    portList.append(str(onePort))
    print(str(onePort))

val = input("COM")

for x in range(0,len(portList)):
    if portList[x].startswith("COM"+str(val)):
        portVal = "COM"+str(val)
        print(portList[x])

serialInst.baudrate = 9600
serialInst.port = portVal
serialInst.open()
while True:
    if serialInst.in_waiting:
        packet = (serialInst.readline()).decode('utf').strip("\n")
        if packet == 'chau':
            serialInst.close()
            break
        print(packet)
```

gracias de antemano :)

Comment: bueno, la solucion era que no le saque al dato el \r
espero esto ayude a alguien mas

Comment: Yo usaria `strip()` sin argumentos. Eso elimina **todos** los espacios en blanco (espacios, tab, `\r`, `\n`), Tal como está, sólo elimina los `\n` pero deja cualquier otra cosa que venga.